# What's the adjective/phrase to describe a romantic novel or TV show that has a detailed description of the (change of) emotion?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

In some romantic novel or TV series, there are many depictions on characters' emotion and the change of emotion. For example, a boy does a favor for a girl, and the novel/TV shows the girl's subtle inner feeling through her subtle unconscious body language, say hands/feet movement. Also, the characters' attitudes towards each other change smoothly and naturally as the story unfolds rather than do it in a rush. The author may also use the mood of the environment to help describing the characters' feeling.

The above are just the possible methods the author may use to show the characters' inner feelings. The methods, of course, are not limited to those described above. Besides, the novel/TV doesn't have to satisfy all of the features/methods above. The idea is that it shows the characters' subtle sentiment in detail. That is, the focus of the question is to use an adjective to differentiate a well-written depiction of inner feeling from rough ones.

What's the adjective/phrase to describe such a romantic novel or TV show? Is there a noun for such a romantic novel or TV show?

Comment: Could you name a few novels or novelists you're talking about?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Haven't read/ watched one in English.

Comment: You could try the word "visceral".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange as it may seem to someone first encountering the huge lexicon of English, there is not an English word for everything humanly conceivable.

I do not know a single English word that captures what you want. (I may be wrong but I am a native speaker whose mother taught English literature.)

Based on what you have indicated, I myself would try

> a psychologically detailed and delicate romance

Comment: Wow, delicate is what I get from the google translation. This meaning is at the bottom of every dictionary explanation page though.

Comment: Given your explanation of the meaning of the word you are trying to translate, I doubt that "delicate" gives all the nuances that you want. It sounds like one of those words that simply cannot be translated into a single word in English. Usually what happens then is that English grabs the word for itself. Linguistic imperialism.

Comment: Yep, I don't feel it captures all the nuances. So, I ask the question here.

Comment: It needs a phrase rather than a single English  word.

Answer (score 0):

A work of fiction that focuses on romantic love and romantic feelings is often called a **romance** ([sense 1a3 in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/romance)), although that word has other meanings, so it is often used in a phrase. **Romantic** is the adjective, although **romance** can be used as an attributive noun, as in the examples below.

A **romance novel** or **romantic novel** is a novel focusing on romance. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_novel))

Similarly, a **romance film** is a film focused on the same themes. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_film#Romantic_drama) discusses this including subtypes.)

A **romantic comedy** or **rom-com** focuses on love and relationships, but is largely funny (although it can have drama and moments of sadness). ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romantic_comedy))

A **romantic drama** is more serious than a romantic comedy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the focus of the question is to use an adjective to differentiate a well-written depiction of inner feeling from rough ones.

Answer (score 0):

Consider "slow burn [romance]" to describe stories where it takes a great deal of time for the romance to officially develop:

> A slow burn is when the romantic attraction between characters builds slowly over the course of a novel or series.
> [What makes a slow burn romance burn?](https://bookriot.com/slow-burn-romances/)

Note that this is more of a name for a particular type of subgenre than a description of how good a romance is. There are good and bad romances that are slow burns and there are good and bad romances that develop quickly.